# jQuery Mouseover AND Mouseout With on AND off not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few functions in jQuery that control the display of a div when the parent div is moused over. The first two functions are :

```
$(".parentDiv").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find(".childDiv").css('visibility','visible');
});

$(".parentDiv").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find(".childDiv").css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

These work fine. Later, I have a click function bound to the 'childDiv':

```
$(".childDiv").click(function (e) {

});
```

I have a bunch of functionality within this function that work perfectly. However, at one point I need to disable the mouseover and mouseout functions on the parent div. I do this by:

```
$("#" + this.id).closest(".parentDiv").off("mouseover mouseout");
```

This works perfectly. But, when I try to turn it on based on other functionality in the function using:

```
$("#" + this.id).closest(".parentDiv").on("mouseover mouseout");
```

It does not turn back on. I know the selector is working, first because it works when I turn it off, but also because I added the following code and it works:

```
$("#" + this.id).closest(".parentDiv").css("border","1px solid #000");
```

Does anyone know why this is not working? I find it strange that turning the mouseover and mouseout off works, and that changing the border also works, but that turning mouseover and mouseout on does not work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because .off doesn't 'turn off' the events, it removes event handlers.

https://api.jquery.com/off/

If you want the events back, you will have to attach them again.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Is there a better way to handle the functionality I am attempting?

Comment: Instead of using .off('mouseover...'), you could change some variable, for example mouseEventsFunctionality = false;  Then, mouseover and mouseout events would always fire, but they could be made to check that variable, and only change visibility if the variable is true. Afterwards, in the logic part where you would 'turn the events on', you revert the variable to true.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up attaching the events again. It just seemed easier with my existing code.

Comment: Yeah, what's better depends partly on your specific implementation.